# retrieve information from firebase and set as an image and label in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I am trying to retrieve some data that Is stored in firebase, and allow that Information to be displayed inside of a collection view. Such as profileImageUrl, name label and email label.

I have tried to read the documentation on firebase and apple website, but for some reason, my code returns plain. I don't receive any errors, but my code is not running as expected. When I go to my app's profile view, the only texts that are displayed are the placeholder that I programmatically placed.

```
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "users")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
 let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "User's Name"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    label.textColor = GREEN_Theme
    return label
}()
let uidLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "User's uid"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = GREEN_Theme
    return label
}()
let emailLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "User's email"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = GREEN_Theme
    return label
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupView()
}

func setupView() {
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return }
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else {
            return }
       let user = CurrentUser(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
        self.uidLabel.text = uid
        self.nameLabel.text = user.name
        self.emailLabel.text = user.email
       self.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(user.profileImageUrl)
    }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
      })  
       self.addSubview(profileImageView)
       self.addSubview(nameLabel)
       self.addSubview(emailLabel)
       self.addSubview(uidLabel)
     profileImageView.anchors(top: topAnchor, topPad: 125, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 75, left: leftAnchor, leftPad: 20, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 250, height: 20, width: 20)
    nameLabel.anchors(top: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, topPad: -50, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left: profileImageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: 20, width: 20)
    emailLabel.anchors(top: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, topPad: -80, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left: profileImageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 125, height: 20, width: 20)
    uidLabel.anchors(top: emailLabel.bottomAnchor, topPad: -40, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left: profileImageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: 20, width: 20)
    profileImageView.layer.zPosition = 10
    nameLabel.layer.zPosition = 10
    emailLabel.layer.zPosition = 10
    profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

 }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help critique what I have, as well as help show me what the correct implementation would look like. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that are not correct.

1. your cell should not be the one in charge of downloading or doing any network call, leave that to the `viewController` or even better a separate handler for all the network calls.
2. Firebase is asynchronous so by the time your data is downloaded all the views have already been set and displayed, that is why you are only seeing your placeholders.
3. You have a lot of redundant code for checking optionals, this is not much of a problem but it is not needed.

You should really think about changing all this code and separating the different tasks to different handlers. For example, you could create a separate class that controls all the calls to Firebase and returns the values with completion blocks, from the viewController or the collectionView itself ask the network handler to give you the data that you need, pass this data to the cell and let the cell display the data, the cell should only display the data, not download it or ask for networks requests. I cannot write up a complete example for you but I think that if you go around in google you will find a lot of very good examples and tutorials.

Anyway, just to get you started and so you have a look at the mistakes that you have in your code, here is a quick fix for it. Even if it works, don't take for granted that everything is fixed. You should really refactor all the code and separate the different tasks. Hope this helps at least so you can solve the problem of displaying your downloaded data in the cell.

```
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "users")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "User's Name"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    label.textColor = GREEN_Theme
    return label
}()
let uidLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "User's uid"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = GREEN_Theme
    return label
}()
let emailLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "User's email"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textColor = GREEN_Theme
    return label
}()


// Here you add a variable that is observed for SET, once a set happens bind() will be called and the views will be updated.
var currentUser : CurrentUser? {
    didSet {
        self.bind()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //...
}


// setupView() should only add the UI appearance, and in this case it is calling firebase and setting currentUser, but it should not do that. This is what you have to refactor.
func setupView() {
    self.addSubview(profileImageView)
    self.addSubview(nameLabel)
    self.addSubview(emailLabel)
    self.addSubview(uidLabel)
    profileImageView.anchors(top: topAnchor, topPad: 125, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 75, left: leftAnchor, leftPad: 20, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 250, height: 20, width: 20)
    nameLabel.anchors(top: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, topPad: -50, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left: profileImageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: 20, width: 20)
    emailLabel.anchors(top: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, topPad: -80, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left: profileImageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 125, height: 20, width: 20)
    uidLabel.anchors(top: emailLabel.bottomAnchor, topPad: -40, bottom: bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, left: profileImageView.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: 20, width: 20)
    profileImageView.layer.zPosition = 10
    nameLabel.layer.zPosition = 10
    emailLabel.layer.zPosition = 10
    profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
    let uid = user.uid
    let reference = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid)
    reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        self.currentUser = CurrentUser(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
    }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
    })
}

// This is the method that updates the cell views.
func bind() {
    self.uidLabel.text = currentUser.uid
    self.nameLabel.text = currentUser.name
    self.emailLabel.text = currentUser.email
    self.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(currentUser.profileImageUrl)
}
```